# How to lazy load an object and it's properties from a json file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to lazy-load an object from a json and be able to use this specific syntax:

```
var myObj = loadFromFile('myObj.json');
console.log(myObj.prop1); //prop1 is loaded here, and nothing else
console.log(myobj); //this loads the rest of the object from the json file


//myObj.json
{
   'prop1': 'val1',
   'prop2': 'val2'
}
```

How could this be achieved, for any object?

EDIT: What I'm trying to find out is if there is any way to proxy the property access operator to load the data on demand, or if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: Is there a practical use-case for this?

Comment: Reducing client memory usage in large applications that load data from large json files, but the clients only need a small part of that file.

Comment: A partial loaded JSON file loses its integrity, which makes it impossible to parse. You could write your own JSON parser for parsing a partial file (or a full file, but returning only a "partial result"), but this could even increase the memory consumption compared to a fully parsed object. It looks like you should use a database instead of JSON files to deliver your data.

Comment: I'm not worried about json integrity, and I'm okay with partial eager pasing, as the benefits of such a system would far outweight the cons.

Comment: Hmm ... If you'll load a large JSON file, all the file content must be kept in the memory, so that you can make partial parses of it. A "realtime" parsing would consume a lot of memory and CPU resources, and it would still be very slow compared to referring a property of a live object in the memory. Take a look at [Weak Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), that is possibly a solution for your problem.